# When I use git pull can I pull a different file based on my operating system?

Tags: git

I have two files that are named nearly identically based on the OS (i.e. `ui.c.osx` for Mac OS X vs. `ui.c.win` for Windows).

When I run a `git pull` I have to rename one of the files based on what operating system I am on (if I pulled on Windows, I have to rename the `ui.c.win` file to `ui.c`).

Is it possible to automatically rename the file when pulling?

I would like it to be built in to git, so if a developer were to pull for the first time with no knowledge the file existed it would just end up getting renamed automatically with no interaction on their part.

Comment: `When I run a git pull I have to rename one of the files based on what operating system I am on ` <-- this sounds like an anti-pattern. Just let your build tool handle it.

Comment: This sounds more like something the "configure" step of a build system would do, not something related to version control.

Comment: why not pull both and conditionally compile/include the appropriate one? `cc ui.c.win -o ui.o`, basically. won't matter WHAT the source filename is, if they both compile to the same .o file.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after another five minutes of Googling: use the `post-checkout` hook as found [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Comment: Now that you have found how, **please don't do it**. Git hooks are a wonderful thing, but what you set to do should be handled by your build system.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why? I am unfamiliar with this realm of things.

Comment: I find it terribly difficult to explain **why is it a bad idea to use a gardening rake to do the work of a shovel**. I'll try: the entire point of `git` (of all VCS) is to have a single, well-identified snapshot of the source for the whole system that you can build for different platforms with your build tool, apply your changes to and commit them on top. You'd lose this. What you'd gain is the *mother of all headaches* when Joe Windows and Jane Linux checkout the same commit, have your hooks perform different changes, do some work, commit their changes and try to merge/rebase their branches.

Comment: Ahh ok. That makes total sense. Didn't think that far ahead. I will look into my build tool then. I feel it is something that should be automated, I was just going about it the wrong way.

Comment: @MiloGerjejansen It is a *great idea* to automate this, but at build level. Look into - depending on your language and toolkit - `cmake`, Maven, `ant`, Gradle, `qmake`. Consider having a look at how some popular projects achieve that. Make sure, while we are at it, that the output of your builds is ignored by `git` by adding the relevant paths to `.gitignore`, so that you can't commit them by mistake and they won't clutter your `git status`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the command line, you can do something like:

```
git pull && mv ui.c.win ui.c
```

If you want to dynamically detect the platform, then you'll need to create a script, and will `mv` based on that. Here is some pseudoy stuff for you.

```
p = os.platform()
switch p
  when 'windows': `mv ui.c.win ui.c`
  when 'mac': `mv ui.c.mac ui.c`
```

then

```
git pull && move_it
```

Alternatively, you can use [githooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)